# CSS flexbox flexwrap alignment and spacing questions

Tags: html, css

I'm building a layout of an iPhone calculator using HTML and CSS, using flex box and flex wrap to order the numbers The `equal` sign should be spanning across the height of numbers as shown but the problem is that I can't make the numbers `4`, `5`, `6` and onward in order, they are "pushed" by the equal button.

How can I keep those number keys close with `7`, `8`, `9` in order and no space between?

I tried other alignment methods in flexbox but resulted in spacing between rows.

In this code there are no spacing between rows which is good. Are there any ways to get the numbers wrap besides the equal button?

```css
#display {
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  width: 320px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

#displayValue {
  color: white;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.operator {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  width: 78px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.operators {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 312px;
  height: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#pad {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 320px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.numbers {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 312px;
  height: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  margin: 0px;
}

.numbers>button {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  width: 78px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#equal {
  background-color: #FA8664;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="display">
      <div id="displayValue">0</div>
    </div>
    <div id="pad">
      <div class="operators">
        <button class="operator">+</button>
        <button class="operator">-</button>
        <button class="operator">×</button>
        <button class="operator">÷</button>
      </div>
      <div class="numbers">
        <button> 7 </button>
        <button> 8 </button>
        <button> 9 </button>
        <button id="equal" , class="operator" , class="equal">=</button>
        <button> 4 </button>
        <button> 5 </button>
        <button> 6 </button>
        <button> 1 </button>
        <button> 2 </button>
        <button> 3 </button>
        <button> 0 </button>
        <button> . </button>
        <button id="clear" , class="operator"> C </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'll be honest, a Calculator layout lends itself much better to a `grid` then a `flexbox` for your purposes, with a nice `grid-template`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question, but a simple way to do it is to correct your **HTML** before tackling the **CSS**.
First remove redundant commas in the declaration of **HTML** element classes(`class="operator", class="equal"`), and spaces around numbers in `<button>` tags.
Create 2 divs in the `.numbers` class, apply a `display: flex;` and remove the height of the equal button.

Try this code and let me know if it works.

```css
#display {
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  width: 320px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

#displayValue {
  color: white;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.operator {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  width: 78px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.operators {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 312px;
  height: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#pad {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 320px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.numbers {
  display: flex;
}

.the-numbers button {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  width: 78px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.equal {
  background-color: #FA8664;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <div id="display">
    <div id="displayValue">0</div>
  </div>
  <div id="pad">
    <div class="operators">
      <button class="operator">+</button>
      <button class="operator">-</button>
      <button class="operator">x</button>
      <button class="operator">÷</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numbers">
      <div class="the-numbers">
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>4</button>
        <button>5</button>
        <button>6</button>
        <button>7</button>
        <button>8</button>
        <button>9</button>
        <button>0</button>
        <button id="clear" class="operator">C</button>
        <button>.</button>
      </div>
      <div class="equal"><button id="equal" class="operator equal">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```